# Como crio um elemento com Vue JS?

Tags: vue.js, formulário, input, dinâmico, component

Fiz essa estrutura bem básica, um componente com input, queria clicar num botão e gerar mais um no html. Tento procurar com appendChild ou v-for ou até v-html, mas não estou conseguindo.

```
let entrada = new Vue({
    template:`
        <input />
    `
})

let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        entrada
}});
```

Answer (score 4):

Sinceramente sua pergunta esta muito ruim, mas lendo as tags acho que entendi mais ou menos o que você quer...
Entendi que você quer montar um formulário de forma dinâmica, se for isso minha recomendação é você pensar em criar modelos de meta dados do formulário que você quer renderizar e ai montar seu form conforme a estrutura de dados desses meta dados.

Exemplo:

```
[
  {
    type: 'Input',
    label: 'My Input Label',
    value: null // ou pode vir com dados carregados do server
  },
  {
    type: 'Checkbox',
    label: 'My Checkbox Label',
    value: [],
    options: ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'] // para simplicidade usando string, mas pode usar um objeto complexo conforme sua necessidade
  }
]
```

Eai basta somente você criar um componente para cada tipo, assim cada componente sabe renderizar e tratar cada tipo de elemento do seu form.

Então o seu componente "Pai", delega item do seu form a um componente "Filho" especifico, porém ele quem sabe qual componente filho usar para rendeziar, tratar e etc.

Segue um pequeno exemplo que fiz no codesandbox:
[image: Edit elegant-jones-6w75r]